# TypeError: _reactNative.StyleSheet.create is not a function when testing a react native app with jest and RTL

Tags: react-native, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm testing a react native app with Jest and React Testing Library, but every time i run the tests i get the following error:

TypeError: _reactNative.StyleSheet.create is not a function

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJZhz.png)

And this particular error is intermittent, sometimes i occurs, sometimes it does not, and the test suites where it throws vary too.

I can't seem to find anything regarding that particular error

Does anybody know how to fix it? And if not how can i tell jest to specifically ignore that error as temporary solution?

Expected Solution: Run the tests without any error